# Safari scrolling div stuck

Tags: html, css, safari, scroll

i' m making a website that have to work with all browsers.
I' ve tested IE, FF, Opera, Chrome and solved a lot of thing related to CSS and jQuery compatibility... but the last thing is making me crazy :(

Safari doesn' t work as it should on the vertical div scrollbar. It is blocked at the bottom of div at the first access. Zooming in/out the page is the only way to unlock it... then it works...

I have this CSS (just a part of it) :

```
html, body {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
background-color:#FFF2E6;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#content {
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:170px;
position:fixed;
float:right;
width:88%; 
height: 85%; 
display:inline;
overflow:auto;
background-color:#E5E5E5;
}

#main_content {
position:static;
width:99.8%; 
height: 85%; 
}
```

The HTML page (just the interested block) :

```
<div id="main_content">
  <div id="menu">
      <p>Menu</p>
      ... menu block ...
  </div>
  <div id="content"><p>Content</p></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to solve the Safari div scroll stuck problem?
Thanks very much for your help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I have a PHP generated page that is printed in the `#content div` via Ajax functions, well, this page has some iframe tags for files upload (the only working trick to upload a file in a jQuery/Ajax context..) These `iframe` had the src property set to `src='#'` what made Safari stuck on a simple div scrolling...

So if you encounter a problem like this just remember to fix your `iframe src="#"` to `iframe src="`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a lucky shot, not sure if it will work:

try using `zoom:1;` in your #content css block. Although its not an widely 'supported' tag but I recall that it did miracles for some css in IE, perhaps it will work for Safari too.

Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: don' t worry man :) thanks anyway for your response. I've tried the zoom css tag but it still not work. Btw i' ve noticed that Chrome is affected too. It seems that all webKit browsers are "div scrolling stuck at first access" bug affected.